# How to create Table from python output

Tags: python

I have written a python program where in I have stored various files in directory. These files have n number of characters.

The code reads these files and prints the

1. File Name
2. length of the file
3. text pattern for certain characters within the file

I have got the following output:

```
36.HomoSapiensHOXD10gene.fa ....... this is the file name
11753.................length of the file for characters
([2296, 2304, 5794, 10258, 11272],)................patterns of text 

37.HomoSapiensHOXD11gene.fa
6139
([],)

38.HomoSapiensHOXD13gene.fa
3648
([403, 2718],)
```

I want show the above outputs in Table format as

[image: Sample output]

Please help

Comment: Hello, what have tried so far? Could you show some code and tell where you got stuck?

Comment: I am not stuck, but unable to figure out a way to convert the above output into table format

Comment: Do you need it to be shown in console using text characters? Did you consider generating HTML-file with table instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your O/P looks like this:

```
36.HomoSapiensHOXD10gene.fa 11753 ([2296, 2304, 5794, 10258, 11272],)
37.HomoSapiensHOXD11gene.fa 6139 ([],)
38.HomoSapiensHOXD13gene.fa 3648 ([403, 2718],)
```

First run your program on terminal like

```
python yourfile.py > yourfile.txt
```

This will copy your output to yourfile.txt
Then use this python code for converting this to a neat table format:

```
import pandas as pd
file_data = open('yourfile.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()  # Read your file
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['file', 'length', 'pattern'])
file = []  # filennames
le = []  #length of file
pattern = []  # patterns
for f in file_data:
    s = f.split(" ", 2) #Two times split on space to get a list of all three parameters
    file_name = s[0].split('.', 1)[1] #extracting just the file name ignoring numbers
    length = s[1]
    patt = s[2].replace('(', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(')', '')  # Removing useless brackets
    try:
        pattern.append(patt.rsplit(',', 1)[0])  # Removing the comma at the end
    except:
        pattern.append('no pattern')
    file.append(file_name)
    le.append(length)
data['file'] = file
data['length'] = le
data['pattern'] = pattern
print(data)
```

Now you will get the desired output if that's what you want. You can also save it in excel/csv format using pandas.

```
                       file length                         pattern
0  HomoSapiensHOXD10gene.fa  11753  2296, 2304, 5794, 10258, 11272
1  HomoSapiensHOXD11gene.fa   6139                                
2  HomoSapiensHOXD13gene.fa   3648                       403, 2718
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the code. But after executing the same I am getting a errorMessage File Name Line Position 
Traceback    
    <module> <module1> 2  
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'HOXgenewithpromoters.txt'. Where Do I need to place this file , I mean where python is installed in that directory

Comment: I am able to get the file now after placing it in a write directory, but getting index not found error file_name = s[0].split('.', 1)[1] #extracting just the file name ignoring numbers

Comment: That means you may have any empty lines, or lines without spaces on which it is splitting. I suggest you to remove empty lines or use try-except statements.

Comment: Thanks I tried it worked but length is coming as blank.

Comment: Maybe your console shrinks the output because the above code I have tested first on my system first. If you haven't got the solution yet, please check if the format provided is correct or post the output.

Comment: Hi, this is the format I have used 
01.HomoSapiensHOXA2gene.fa  3058  ([1675, 1696],)  this is the output I am getting                         file                        ...                                                                    pattern
0    HomoSapiensHOXA1gene.fa                        ...                                                                 3604  3574.  The length and pattern are coming together and length header is not displayed

Comment: That ... actually means that your output is shrinking on console. You can append that output in a file to check it works just fine. Use **python above_code.py > output.txt**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this with prettytable

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = ["Field Name", "Length", "Pattern"]
x.add_row(["HOXD10gene.fa", 11753, [2296, 2304, 5794, 10258, 11272]])
print(x)
```

You can try importing the data from a csv file as below

```
from prettytable import from_csv
with open("data.csv", "r") as fp: 
x = from_csv(fp)
print(x)
```

Comment: I am not able to import prettytable

Comment: Sorry installed the same from pip,it worked beautifully, thanks a ton

Comment: I have one question. I have copied the output into text file and then added the rows individually in the code. I added x.add_row multiple times. How do I loop through these rows by directly reading the same from the text file. Can you please suggest

Comment: You can best import the data from a csv file. I have updated the post